# Expo Layout When headerShown: false my app take all of height why?

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, react-navigation

im working on my app and i use expo react-native and there is the default i dont want a header bar but when i make the command  headerShown: false all of my screen come up most than i expect
[here you can see my app go on the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJsi2.png) and that the same for all of my screen :[here you can see where my text begin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wK2p.png)

I hope some one could help me here is a code test who have the same problems :

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <Stack
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
            }}>
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

I try something looking more like that :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cVbX.png) ,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woQu3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SafeAreaView provided by either [expo](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/) or [react-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview). The expo version has a [hook](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/#hooks) to provide higher control over the padding used when combined with a [View](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view) component. The insets provide the padding values for top, bottom, right, and left that are needed to push the views content out of the status bars.

For your case, the insets combined with a normal view may work better since it seems that you are using bottom tabs. If you used the SafeAreaView component for the screens, then extra bottom padding might show up on devices that need bottom safe area paddding (like the newer iPhones).

Depending on the how you want to implement this solution, you could either use the SafeAreaView insets hook with each screen that you create, or you could wrap your Layout Stack component in a view that utilizes the padding from the SafeAreaView insets.